# How to display the page range of marked locations in a passage in ConTeXt?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, context, context-mkiv

I have a macro placed throughout my document marking key places within a long passage. These have no relation to the chapter or section titles.

```
 _____________ _____________
|             |             |
| .....a..... | ........... |
| .........b. | ..d........ |
| ........... | ........... |
| ........... | ........... |
| ........... | ........... |
| ....c...... | .......e... |
| ........... | ........... |
|______1______|______2______|

 _____________ _____________
|             |             |
| ....f...... | ........... |
| .......g... | ........... |
| ...h....... | .....j..... |
| ........... | ........... |
| ........... | Section.... |
| .......i... | ..........k |
| ........... | ........... |
|______3______|______4______|
```

I need to place information in the headers, to tell readers the current page range of the markings of the portion of text they are currently reading, e.g.:

```
 _____________ _____________
| c: 1-2      | e: 2-3      |
| .....a..... | ........... |
| .........b. | ..d........ |
| ........... | ........... |
| ........... | ........... |
| ........... | ........... |
| ....c...... | .......e... |
| ........... | ........... |
|______1______|______2______|

 _____________ _____________
| e: 2-3      | j: 4-4      |
| ........... | ........... |
| ........... | ........... |
| ........... | .....j..... |
| ........... | ........... |
| ........... | Section.... |
| ........... | ........... |
| ........... | ..........k |
|______3______|______4______|
```

- As some pages, have multiple ranges, the last range appearing on the page can be displays.

How can I place information in the headers of my document to tell readers the page range of the current portion of the text they are reading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a `\rangestart{rangename}` and `\rangestop{rangename}` macro, make them store the page numbers across runs, and make a function to select and print any ranges that are active on a given page number.

I stole the `job.datasets.setdata` / `job.datasets.getdata` syntax from [phg's construction for a different multi-pass question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72810/2229). Hope this helps!

```
\startluacode
    userdata = userdata or {}
    local ranges_start_tmp = {}

    -- record range name and start in temp. array, to be
    -- flushed to the .tuc file when we also know the stop.
    function userdata.rangestart(rangename, page)
        ranges_start_tmp[rangename] = page
    end

    -- flush range name, start, and stop to the .tuc file.
    function userdata.rangestop(rangename, page)
        job.datasets.setdata({
            name = "ranges",
            data = {
                ["name"]  = rangename,
                ["start"] = ranges_start_tmp[rangename],
                ["stop"]  = page,
            }
        })
        ranges_start_tmp[rangename] = nil
    end

    -- Takes 3 arguments: the page whose active ranges to describe,
    -- a template{name, start, stop} for formatting a single range,
    -- and a separator to print between multiple ranges
    function userdata.printranges(page, template, sep)
        local ranges = {}

        local i = 1
        local range = job.datasets.getdata("ranges", i) -- default: nil
        while range do
            if range.start <= page and page <= range.stop then
                ranges[#ranges + 1] = string.formatters[template](
                    range.name, range.start, range.stop
                )
            end
            i = i + 1
            range = job.datasets.getdata("ranges", i)
        end

        context(table.concat(ranges, sep))
    end
\stopluacode

% The TeX side of the mechanism
\define[1]\rangestart{\ctxlua{userdata.rangestart([[#1]], \userpage)}}
\define[1]\rangestop{\ctxlua{userdata.rangestop([[#1]], \userpage)}}
\define[3]\printranges{\ctxlua{userdata.printranges(#1, #2, #3)}}

% -------------------------
% Let's try it out

% Templates contain percent signs -- better to write them in a lua
% block.
\startluacode
    userdata.mytemplate = "%s, from %i to %i"
\stopluacode
\setupheadertexts[\printranges{\userpage}{userdata.mytemplate}{"; "}]
\setupfootertexts[\userpage]

\setuppapersize[A6, landscape]

\starttext
    \section{A}
        \input knuth
        \input knuth
    \section{B}
        \rangestart{a}
        \input knuth
        \rangestop{a}
        \rangestart{b}
    \section{C}
        \input knuth
        \rangestop{b}
\stoptext
```

Comment: Rather than a global `mytemplate` it is better to use `usersdata.range_template` so as not to pollute the global name space

Comment: I had hoped to get away with laziness, but the devil makes work for idle hands. :-P Corrected.